# Can Mathematica automatically optimize an expression with PowerMod?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, modular-arithmetic

`PowerMod[x,p,m]` is significantly faster than `Mod[x^p, m]` for a large `p`

I have an expression, say `12*5^p + 33*9^p + 15`, and I need the value mod 1007 for some integer p. For a large p it's significantly faster to calculate `Mod[12*PowerMod[5,p,1007] + 33*PowerMod[9,p,1007] + 15, 1007]`.

Now, my actual expression is much more complicated and it's a result of previous code. So it's a chore (not to mention error prone) for me to manually add `PowerMod` at the appropriate places.

My question is, can Mathematica somehow automatically find where to put PowerMod in an expression of the form `Mod[expression, 1007]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
12*5^p + 33*9^p + 15 /. x_^y_ -> PowerMod[x, y, 1007]
```

Output:

```
15 + 11 PowerMod[3, 1 + 2 p, 1007] + 12 PowerMod[5, p, 1007]
```